# ruby gem list comand seems to list to rails version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

when I run gem list command in the terminal window I get the following:
    rails (5.0.0, 4.2.5)
when I run rails -v I get rails 4.2.5
Originally the gem file had rails 5.0.0 but I changed it.
Does rails (5.0.0, 4.2.5) mean that there are 2 rails versions associated with this app or is it something else?

thanks

Comment: no, it means you have at some time installed two different version of Rails and the current one installed for this app is 5.0.0 The other one is sitting in cache in case you ever want to use it again.

Comment: i think rvm is best for managing multiple version of ruby